# How to forward to new URL including all the variables?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have been providing my subdomain name to friend until he manages to get new domain.

Now he has it and I would like to 301 redirect all the old links to his domain:

Example:

```
http://subdomain.my-domain.com/post.php?118&tg=602643
```

Redirect to

```
http://subdomain.com/post.php?118&tg=602643
```

So I want to keep up all the variables behind the post.php in the redirect

I am .htaccess newbie - can you please help me with providing the correct Rewrite rule?

Also, If you happen to have any good article about .htaccess and how to manage it, link is really appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**
Here are actual usecases I want to do:
 redirect

```
 http://raketa2.tasselhof.com/nastenka.php?115&up=648483
```

to

```
 http://www.raketa2.cz/nastenka.php?115&up=648483
```

However, since there is no more subdomain existent on my site, i see the 404 error on my main page as this:

```
/nastenka.php?115&up=648483 -> Provided 404 Error
```

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{Request_URI} ^/nastenka\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\d+&tg=\d+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.raketa2.cz/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

But with no good...

**SOLVED**
Duh! I am really dumb. I just added two new CNAME records to my domain DNS. Should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
RewrtiteEngine on
ReWriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.com/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

The QUERY_STRING `post.php?118&tg=602643` will be present.

---

> - Assuming that there is no `post.php` on your domain,

Do this:

```
RewrtiteEngine on
ReWriteBase /

RewriteCond %{Request_URI} ^/post\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.com/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

---

> - If `post.php` is present on your domain but, you do not use similar query strings,

Do this:

```
RewrtiteEngine on
ReWriteBase /

RewriteCond %{Request_URI} ^/post\.php [NC]
RFewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\d+&tg=\d+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.com/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I forgot to mention - since the subdomain is non existent on my site, I got these in 404 logs in my own domain. And I would like also to redirect `http://my-domain.com/post.php?118&tg=602643` to `http://subdomain.com/post.php?118&tg=602643` - how do I do that?

Comment: didnt help. I also updated my question with exact usecase and your help... Still 404